# Download file using python without knowing its extension. - content-type - stream

Tags: python, python-3.x, stream, http-headers, python-requests

Hey i just did some research and found that i could download images from urls which end with *filename.extension* like *000000.jpeg*. i wonder now how i could downoad a picture which doesnt have any extension.
Here is my url which i want to download the image http://books.google.com/books/content?id=i2xKGwAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api
when i put the url directly to the browser it displays an image

furthermore here is what i tried:

```
from six.moves import urllib

thumbnail='http://books.google.com/books/content?id=i2xKGwAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api'

img=urllib.request.Request(thumbnail)
pic=urllib.request.urlopen(img)
pic=urllib.request.urlopen(img).read()
```

Anyhelp will be appreciated so much

Comment: you'd have to look at the content-type header and then transform that into a file ending.

Comment: if you look at the first 20 bytes or so you will see JFIF as part of its magic string ... this is the identifier for jpg ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a way to do it using HTTP response headers :

```
import requests
import time

r = requests.get("http://books.google.com/books/content?id=i2xKGwAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api", stream=True)
ext = r.headers['content-type'].split('/')[-1] # converts response headers mime type to an extension (may not work with everything)
with open("%s.%s" % (time.time(), ext), 'wb') as f: # open the file to write as binary - replace 'wb' with 'w' for text files
    for chunk in r.iter_content(1024): # iterate on stream using 1KB packets
        f.write(chunk) # write the file
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but i wanted to get the image files. Your code prints only 1024 numbers. is there a way i can get the file ?

Comment: this downloads the file. I'm surprised it prints anything.
Are you using python2 ?

Comment: I got the file thanks.i was testing the code in the python shell thats why i was a bit confused, and where can i get the information about headers

Comment: you should take a look at HTTP response headers.
I like MDN documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers

Comment: you can also press F12 on your brower, open the network tab, select a request, and see for yourself.

Comment: Nice one i appreciate your help